# Read in file, Filter out records, output results

Tags: python, statistics, modules, natural-language-processing, matplotlib

I have been working on a project for some time and have let one Python file grow into a huge file that tries to do everything. The structure is pretty flat and I don't like it. I've used other programming languages like Java and C# and have had pretty structured code, but for some reason in Python I always let it turn into a flat mess.

This code basically reads in files of serialized data, and filters some out based on criteria, spitting the results out to a file. Does any one have some high level tips about how I could have approached this better? I am not looking for details of particular lines, but just sort of the project as a whole.

```
import string
import os.path
import os
import time
import datetime
import dill
import argparse
from multiprocessing import Process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

EXCLUDED_POS = ['NNP', 'NN', 'VBP', 'VBD', '.', 'CC', 'DT', 'NNS', 'IN', 'PRP',
                'TO', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'VBG', ',', 'VBN', 'VBZ', 'WP']
WORDS = ['not', '\'nt']
REMOVABLE_TYPES = ['advmod', # includes quantmod
                   'amod',
                   # 'appos', too few
                   'compound',
                   # 'nmod:npmod', too few
                   # 'nummod', # Same ate [3] sheep [number and num
                   # usually needed
                   #'quantmod', # included in 'advmod'
                   #'nmod:poss', # Bill's clothes ['poss'] - lots of u
                   # ungrammatical results
                   # 'det:predet', # All the boys are here ['predet'] too few
                   # 'case', # prepositions - too many and most were needed
                   # TODO DSF - mark the whole prepositional phrase maybe?
                   # but lots of mistakes
                   'nmod:tmod',  # aren't too many, but interesting, also aren't
                   # many types (lots of 'one day') - i think we could learn
                   # here
                   #'vmod' #     didn't exist, under xcomp, but too general
                   ]
DELIMITER = '|'
TOKENS_WITHOUT_SPACE = ["'", ".", "!", ":", ",", "n't"]
WORDS_TO_FILTER_OUT = ['when',
                       'so',
                       'just',
                       'hardly',
                       'how',
                       'why']


def filter_word_type(sent, dparsed_list, dparsed_item_key, dparsed_item_value):
    """Filters the passed in list by the removable word types."""
    return dparsed_item_value['rel'] in REMOVABLE_TYPES


def filter_out_words(sent, dparsed_list, dparsed_item_key, dparsed_item_value):
    """Filters out certain words"""
    return dparsed_item_value['word'] not in WORDS_TO_FILTER_OUT


def filter_out_circumscribed_mods(sent, dparsed_list, dparsed_item_key,
                                  dparsed_item_value):
    """Modifiers that have modifiers cannot be removed
    e.g.: Very happy person. Happy can't be removed in this case
    """

    return dparsed_list.nodes[int(dparsed_item_value['head'])]['rel']\
        not in REMOVABLE_TYPES


def plot_frequencies(data, ax, legend_label):
    # now sort tuples by count
    data = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)

    # tuples (pair,count)
    x = [t[0] for t in data]
    y = [t[1] for t in data]

    x_pos = np.arange(len(x))

    ax.plot(x_pos, y, label=legend_label)
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    plt.xlim([0, len(x)])
    plt.ylim([.5, y[0]])


def get_statistics_for_sentence(prev_stats, dsent, interesting_records):
    prev_stats['count'] += len(interesting_records)
    prev_stats['sentences'] += 1

    for i, r in interesting_records.items():
        # stanford type
        r_t = r['rel']
        r_pos = r['tag']

        ts = prev_stats['types']

        if r_t not in ts:
            ts[r_t] = {}
            ts[r_t]['count'] = 0
            ts[r_t]['pos'] = {}

        ts[r_t]['count'] += 1

        if r_pos not in ts[r_t]['pos']:
            ts[r_t]['pos'][r_pos] = 0

        ts[r_t]['pos'][r_pos] += 1

        # add the head, modifier, and modifier-head counts
        head = dsent[int(r['head'])]['word']
        mod = r['word']

        m = prev_stats['modifiers']
        if mod not in m:
            m[mod] = {}

        if head not in m[mod]:
            m[mod][head] = 0

        m[mod][head] += 1

        h = prev_stats['heads']

        if head not in h:
            h[head] = 0

        h[head] += 1


def remove_dependent_nodes(nodes, i, remove_list):
    last_node_ind = -1
    total_skipped = 0

    for j, n in nodes.items():
        next_index = j - last_node_ind

        if next_index is not 1:
            total_skipped += (next_index - 1)
        last_node_ind = j

        if j == 0:
            continue
        if int(n['head']) == i:
            remove_list.append(j - total_skipped)
            remove_dependent_nodes(nodes, j, remove_list)


def write_line(story, nodes, trigger_node, words_to_remove, output_file,
               story_filename, sentence_num, preremove, to_delete, postremove):
    words_to_remove = sorted(set(words_to_remove))

    output_file.write(story.source + DELIMITER +
                      story.storyid + DELIMITER +
                      story_filename + DELIMITER + story.full_story +
                      DELIMITER + story.original_title +
                      DELIMITER + str(sentence_num))

    # Output the full sentence
    full_sentence = story.original_sentences[sentence_num].replace(
                    '\r', '').replace('\n', '')
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + full_sentence)

    output_file.write(DELIMITER + trigger_node['rel'])

    # Output the interesting words
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + trigger_node['word'])
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + nodes[int(trigger_node['head'])]['word'])

    output_file.write(DELIMITER + preremove)
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + to_delete)
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + postremove)
    # words to remove
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + str(words_to_remove[0]))
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + str(words_to_remove[-1]))

    # head word index
    output_file.write(DELIMITER + str(trigger_node['head']))
    output_file.write('\r\n')


def handle_sentence(story, story_filename, sentence_num, output_file, stats,
                    filter_list, filter_stats):
    """Handle the given sentence and output the results to output_file."""
    # parse the sentence
    # now it is just a matter of iterating over our items and removing them
    # one by one
    # first, get just the set we care about
    count = 0

    # get the first dependency tree
    dsent = story.dparsed_sentences[sentence_num]
    sent = story.original_sentences[sentence_num]

    # get the triples of the dep graph
    p = [list(parse.triples()) for parse in dsent]

    dsent = dsent[0]
    interesting_records = dsent.nodes
    for filter_func in filter_list:
        pre_filter_count = len(interesting_records)

        interesting_records = {k: v for k, v in interesting_records.items() if
            filter_func(sent, dsent, k, v)}

        post_filter_count = len(interesting_records)

        # Add this to our statistics
        if pre_filter_count != post_filter_count:
            filter_stats[filter_func.__qualname__] +=\
                pre_filter_count - post_filter_count

    count = len(interesting_records)

    # Get statistics based on the sentence
    results = get_statistics_for_sentence(stats, dsent.nodes,
                                          interesting_records)

    # if the count is greater than 0, we have something to remove, so let's go!
    if count == 0:
        return results

    # INTERESTING SENTENCE FOUND - let's write it out to the file
    words_with_apos = 0
    words_seen = -1

    for i, n in dsent.nodes.items():
        words_seen += 1
        if i == 0:
            continue
        # Weird quirk for counting - we need to count apostrophes differently
        if "'" in n['word']:
            words_with_apos += 1

        words_to_remove = []
        # check to see if the node has any of the phenomena we care about
        # TODO DSF see if it is in the interesting_records list??
        if i in interesting_records.keys():
            # This is the occurrence we should consider,
            # so do the work
            words_to_remove.append(words_seen - words_with_apos)

            # also remove any dependent nodes
            remove_dependent_nodes(dsent.nodes, i, words_to_remove)
            words_to_remove.sort()
            # Now, let's build up the sentence into parts:
            # 1) Before the words to be removed
            # 2) the words to be removed
            # 3) the words after the words to be removed        .
            to_delete = ''
            split_sent = sent.split()
            last_ind_pre_remove = words_to_remove[0] - 1
            if last_ind_pre_remove < 0:
                last_ind_pre_remove = 0

            first_ind_post_remove = words_to_remove[-1]
            if first_ind_post_remove > len(split_sent):
                first_ind_post_remove = len(split_sent) - 1

            preremove = " ".join(split_sent[0: last_ind_pre_remove]).strip()
            postremove = " ".join(split_sent[first_ind_post_remove:]).strip()
            for i in split_sent[
                        words_to_remove[0] - 1: words_to_remove[-1]
                        ]:
                to_delete += i + ' '
            to_delete = to_delete[:-1].strip()

            # print(split_sent)
            # print("Start: " + str(words_to_remove[0]) + "End: " +
            #        str(words_to_remove[-1]))
            # print(preremove + ' [' + to_delete + '] ' + postremove)

            # Fix up our punctuation a bit
            preremove, to_delete, postremove = clean_sentence(preremove,
                                                              to_delete,
                                                              postremove)

            # Finally, write out the line to the fs
            write_line(story, dsent.nodes, n, words_to_remove, output_file,
                       story_filename, sentence_num, preremove, to_delete,
                       postremove)

def clean_sentence(preremove, to_delete, postremove):
    """Takes in parts of the sentence and cleans them up for output.
    This includes making a->an, making first words capitalized, and outputting
    periods where they belong.
    """

    # Capitalize the first letter of the sentence
    # This can only happen if the deleted section contains the first word
    # of the sentence
    if len(preremove) == 0:
        postremove = postremove.capitalize()[0] + postremove[1:]

    # Remove punctuation that is at the end of the middle section and move
    # it to the outside
    # e.g. [He was feeling] [well.] [] -> [He was feeling] [well] [.]
    if len(postremove) == 0 and to_delete[-1] in string.punctuation:
        postremove = str(to_delete[-1])
        to_delete = to_delete[:-1]

    # make 'a' -> 'an' if appropriate
    # We only need compare the last word of the beginning with the first
    # of the end
    if len(preremove) != 0 and len(postremove) != 0:
        end = preremove.split()[-1].lower()
        first = postremove[0].lower().strip()

        if end == 'a' and first in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
            preremove = preremove + 'n'
        elif end == 'an' and first not in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
            preremove = preremove[:-1]

    # Make sure we have a period at the end
    if len(postremove) != 0:
        if postremove[-1:] not in string.punctuation:
            postremove = postremove + '.'
    else:
        if to_delete[-1:] not in string.punctuation:
            to_delete = to_delete + '.'

    return preremove, to_delete, postremove


def output_filter_stats(output_path, filter_stats):
    with open(output_path + 'filter_stats', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Totals by Filter Type: \r\n')

        for k, v in filter_stats.items():
            f.write(k + ": " + str(v) + '\r\n')


def output_stats(output_path, stats):
    if not os.path.isdir(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)

    with open(output_path + 'general', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Phenomena per sentence: ' +
                str(stats['count'] / stats['sentences']) + '\r\n')

        f.write('Phenomena per story: ' +
                str(stats['count'] / stats['stories']) + '\r\n')

        f.write('Dependency Types:\r\n')

        for k,v in stats['types'].items():
            f.write('\t'  + str(k) + ": " + str(v['count']) + '\r\n')

        f.write('POS:\r\n')

        for k,v in stats['types'].items():
            f.write('\t' + k + ':\r\n')

            for k,v in v['pos'].items():
                f.write('\t\t' + k + ': ' + str(v) + '\r\n')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    with open(output_path + 'heads_and_modifiers.csv', 'w') as f:
        # try to bring everything together and sort it

        # header
        f.write('modifier' + DELIMITER + 'head' + DELIMITER + 'count' +
                DELIMITER + 'total mod count' + DELIMITER +
                'perc with this head\r\n')
        all_items = []

        for k,v in stats['modifiers'].items():
            total = sum(v.values())
            for k2, v2 in v.items():
                # figure out the total for this modifier and the perc
                f.write(k + DELIMITER + k2 + DELIMITER +
                        str(v2) + DELIMITER + str(total) +
                        DELIMITER + str(v2/total)+'\r\n')
                all_items.append((k + k2, v2))

        start_time = time.time()

        plot_frequencies(all_items, ax, 'Modifier/Head')

        end_time = time.time()
        full_time = end_time - start_time
        print('Time at the end: ' + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=full_time)))



    with open(output_path + 'heads.csv', 'w') as f:
        all_heads = []
        # header
        f.write('head' + DELIMITER + 'count\r\n')

        for k,v in stats['heads'].items():
            f.write(k + DELIMITER + str(v) + '\r\n')
            all_heads.append((k, v))

        plot_frequencies(all_heads, ax, 'Head')

    with open(output_path + 'modifiers.csv', 'w') as f:
        all_mods = []
        # header
        f.write('modifier' + DELIMITER + 'count\r\n')

        for k,v in stats['modifiers'].items():
            s = sum(v.values())
            f.write(k + DELIMITER + str(s) + '\r\n')
            all_mods.append((k, s))

        plot_frequencies(all_mods, ax, 'Modifier')


    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(output_path + '/freq_dist.png')


def finish_up(output_dir, stats, filter_stats):
    output_stats(output_dir + '/stats/', stats)
    output_filter_stats(output_dir + '/stats/', filter_stats)


def do_loop(file_list, process_num, output_dir, filter_list):
    # Captures the stats about how many elements were removed due to various
    # filters
    filter_stats = {}

    for f in filter_list:
        filter_stats[f.__qualname__] = 0

    prev_stats = {}
    prev_stats['count'] = 0  # total number of phenomena
    prev_stats['types'] = {}  # types of phenomena
    prev_stats['sentences'] = 0  # sentence count
    prev_stats['stories'] = 0  # story count
    prev_stats['modifiers'] = {}  # modifiers, their count, and their heads
                                  # {'modifier': {'head': count}}
    prev_stats['heads'] = {}  # {'head': count}
    stories_processed = 0

    output_file = output_dir + '/sentences_' + str(i) + '.csv'
    with(open(output_file, 'w')) as o:
        # Write a header
        o.write('Source' + DELIMITER +
                          'StoryID' + DELIMITER +
                          'File' + DELIMITER +
                  'Full Story' + DELIMITER +
                          'Title' + DELIMITER +
                          'Sentence Number' + DELIMITER +
                          'Original Sentence' + DELIMITER +
                          'Modifier Type' + DELIMITER +
                          'Modifier' + DELIMITER +
                          'Head' + DELIMITER +
                          'Preremove Sentence Part' + DELIMITER +
                          'To Remove Part' + DELIMITER +
                          'Postremove Sentence Part' + DELIMITER +
                          'Removed Words Start Index' + DELIMITER +
                          'Removed Words End Index' + DELIMITER +
                          'Head Word Index'+
                          '\r\n')

        # go through each file and process the information we care about
        # including which words could be removed
        start_time = time.time()
        for f in file_list:
            # deserialize the story
            story = dill.load(open(f, 'rb'))

            prev_stats['stories'] += 1
            for line_num, sent in enumerate(story.dparsed_sentences):
                handle_sentence(story, f, line_num, o, prev_stats,
                                filter_list, filter_stats)

            stories_processed += 1
            if stories_processed % 500 == 0:
                end_time = time.time()
                full_time = end_time - start_time
                print("Proc " + str(process_num) + ": " +
                    str(stories_processed) + " Time: "
                    + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=full_time)))


        finish_up(output_dir, prev_stats, filter_stats)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Determine the set of \
                                        potentially removable modifiers for the\
                                        sentences in the provided input \
                                        directory')
    argparser.add_argument('input_directory',
                           help='The path to the input files.')
    argparser.add_argument('procs',
                           help='The number of processors to use.')
    argparser.add_argument('output_directory',help='The output path.')
    argparser.add_argument('--run_all_filter_combinations',
                           help='Should we run all filter combinations, or\
                           just the passed in list? (T|F)', default=False)
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    proc_count = int(args.procs)

    # Get the number of lines in a file
    file_list = [args.input_directory + '/' +
                 f for f in os.listdir(args.input_directory)]
    total = len(file_list)

    print('Files to process: ' + str(total))

    interval = int(int(total) / int(proc_count))
    print(str(proc_count) + " processes, each processing " + str(interval) +
          ' records')

    if not os.path.isdir(args.output_directory):
        os.makedirs(args.output_directory)
    for i in range(0, proc_count):

        range_start = (i * interval)

        if i == (proc_count - 1):
            range_end = total - 1
        else:
            range_end = ((i + 1) * interval) - 1

        # Let's set our filter list
        filter_list = [
            filter_word_type,
            filter_out_words,
            filter_out_circumscribed_mods
            ]

        print('[' + str(range_start) + ':' + str(range_end) + ']')
        # make a process for each grouping
        p = Process(target=do_loop,
                    args=(file_list[range_start:range_end], i,
                          args.output_directory, filter_list))
        p.start()
```

Comment: That title is kinda misleading , I would recommend to change the title to something like 'Code for ......' for help read [it](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions]) .

Comment: I fixed it. Is that better?

Comment: Could you add the [tag:python-2.7] or [tag:python-3.x] tag please? Also lots of programs filter records from files, maybe use the description from the `argparse` parser as a starting point for the title?

Comment: I I tried in the beginning, but I don't have sufficient permission to.

Comment: Please tell us more about the motivation, the inputs, and expected outputs of this code.

Comment: I'm more just looking for general advice - how I should structure my code in general, irrespective of the motivation. When you look at it, does it strike you in any way that it is wrong. (Example: "A function should do one thing, and you have a lot of code in each of your functions. Break them out into a more functions, or helper modules.")